# How to keep instances within the volume

Tags: materials, volumetrics, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to create cookie chips within a chocolate with geometry nodes. I've managed to create the instances but within the surface. And all the references/tutorials (even blender description of the nodes) are mostly from the previous version not the latest 3.0 version of it :(! Not sure how to make this instances to remain within the shape of the chocolate, any help?

[image: chocolate preview]
[image: Geometric node tree]

Answer (score 4):

This setup worked for me. Basically you can move the points inwards along the normal.

- The position of each distributed points is offset based on the normal at that point on the mesh.
- The normal is scaled with a negative number so that the points move inwards rather than outwards.
- In this case I captured the vertex normal instead of using the normal output directly from the distribute node because it is smoother around the corners of the cube, but I doubt it would make a difference for you, since your instances are much smaller and there are fewer of them.

[image: Offsetting the position of distributed points based on the normal]